# Android app gives error W/BroadcastQueueInjector

Tags: android

I am building widget app for Andriod.
But it gives error, the log appear in LogCat

```
2021-08-14 06:17:22.730 1593-1738/? W/BroadcastQueueInjector: Unable to launch app com.lablnet.covid19pakistanwidget/10334 for broadcast Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED flg=0x10 cmp=com.lablnet.covid19pakistanwidget/.covidWidget }: process is not permitted to appointed component no autostart
```

My manifest file are as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lablnet.covid19pakistanwidget">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Covid19PakistanWidget">


        <receiver android:name=".covidWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/covid_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java Widget Activiy file

```java
package com.lablnet.covid19pakistanwidget;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class covidWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {



        final @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout") RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.covid_widget);

        Thread t = new Thread((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String dataToShow =DataReader.GetData();
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidgettext, dataToShow);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        }));
        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);//add this line
        Log.d("R", "Recievbed");
        if (MyOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Log.d("R", "Recievbed");
        }
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }

    private static final String MyOnClick = "myOnClickTag";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)
        {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Also, it works fine on Emulators and andriod 7,6 and below version.
But does not works in version 8,9,10 and 11. I tested in different phone Samsung, Infinix, xiaomi

Am stucked on that error, help me to solve it .

The whole code found here: https://github.com/lablnet/covid19-pak-widget-android
(Am fixing that error)
Thanks